# Dequeue Twilio call reservation to a conference room

Tags: javascript, php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to dequeue an enqueued inbound call to a conference room using PHP/Symfony and the JavaScript Voice SDK.

What I have working now is dequeuing the call to an individual agent.  But I want to enable supervisory monitoring and coaching.  For this, it seems, I need a conference room.

On the server side I enqueue the call using the default "Assign to Anyone" workflow...

```
        $voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse;
        $enqueue = $voiceResponse->enqueue('',['workflowSid' => $ccmanager->getWorkflowSid()]);
        $xml = $voiceResponse->asXml();
        $response = new Response($xml, Response::HTTP_OK, ['context-type' => 'text/xml']);
        return $response;
```

Client side, when one of the agents decides to pick up the call, I dequeue the reservation...

```
this.dequeueReservation = function(data)
{
    let contactUri = self.getContactUri();
    let reservation = self.getReservation(data.phone_number);
    if(reservation) {
        console.log('before reservation dequeue');
        reservation.dequeue(
            null,
            null,
            'record-from-answer',
            30, // seconds to answer
            'https://d72d-76-18-83-142.ngrok.io/anon/voice/status', // status callback url
            'initiated,ringing,answered,completed',
            contactUri,
            (error, newReservation) => onDequeue(data, error, newReservation)
        );
    }
}
```

Where getContactUri() is...

```
this.getContactUri = function() {
    switch(self.agent.call_routing) {
        case 'workstation':
            return 'client:' + self.agent.worker_name;
        case 'business_phone':
            return '+1' + self.agent.business_phone;
        case 'other_phone':
            return '+1' + self.agent.other_phone;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

So all this works great, but there is no way to add supervisor functions with this approach (apparently).  What I need to do (apparently) is to dequeue the reservation to a conference room and then separately connect the agent to the conference room.

This would be easy if I was able to create a contactUri for a conference room.  However there does not seem to be a 'conference_room:" form of the contactUri however.

Alternately I could perhaps, server-side, route the inbound call first to a conference room and then enqueue the conference room.  This does not seem possible.

In any event I need the task queue as part of the solution so I can properly route calls to the various agents.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dequeue to a conference, you can use either the REST API or the Taskrouter Javascript client.

### REST API

[Update a Member Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/member-resource?code-sample=code-update-a-member-resource&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x)

```
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.queues('QUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .members('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .update({url: 'https://example.com'})
      .then(member => console.log(member.callSid));
```

The url is the above example is the url that will return Twiml for a conference.

[Create A Simple Conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference?code-sample=code-a-simple-conference&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=4.x)

```
const VoiceResponse = require('twilio').twiml.VoiceResponse;


const response = new VoiceResponse();
const dial = response.dial();
dial.conference('Room 1234');

console.log(response.toString());
```

The Twiml that A Simple Conference produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room 1234</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

### Taskrouter.js Client

[Use reservation.conference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#reservation-conference)

```
reservation.conference(
    "18004746453",
    "WAxxx",
    "30",
    "client:joey",
    function(error, reservation) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
            console.log(error.message);
            return;
        }
        console.log("conference initiated");
    }
);
```

Comment: Right.  But I don't understand how reservations are involved with your approach. The reservations are key to determining which agent answers the call.  If 10 agents are online and a call is enqueued, a reservation is created for all 10 agents.  One agent will accept the reservation and the other 9 reservations will be canceled.

Comment: I didn't pick-up that you were using TaskRouter, I thought just the Enqueue feature...I don't think TaskRouter will make a reservation for all 10 agents (just the first matching worker), but I haven't used that component very much. Here is a page on how to use TaskRouter to dequeue using [Conference Instructions](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/reservations?code-sample=code-update-conference-instructions&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x). Your first worker will Accept the reservation and then issue the Conference Instruction.

Comment: Yes, it will.  There is a "Maximum reserved Workers" on each task queue which allows multiple workers to be reserved for each task.  Default is 1.  So it seems that there is a reservation.conference() function in the task router SDK that does what I want.  Your comment put me on the right track.  So if you update your answer to use this instruction (and I manage to get it to work) I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: Great, I just refined the answer. Glad it helped (even a little).

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: Yes!  Sorry it took some time to get around to testing this.  Major misunderstanding on my part of how this works.  I was trying to dequeue the call then then conference it.  Doesn't work that way.  Forget dequeing the call and simply conference it.  Does not seem optimal because how do I know I will need a conference before I answer the call?  Putting every inbound call into a conference seems to be the only way to provide the flexibility you might need to forward calls, coach, listen in, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: The prototype I am working on does not dequeue to a conference using the built-in dequeue to conference because I am not using Taskrouter. Instead, I use the redirect option which allows me to redirect the call with specific Twiml (that ends up in a conference). Don't be put off by the term "conference"...Think of it as a voicecall with many more features. You will probably have many "conferences" with only two participants.